# In JavaScript, what is the ultimate root, Object or Function?

Tags: javascript, function, object

In JavaScript is Object the root of all entities or Function is the root?

For example in the following source [objects-functions-and-prototypes-in.html](http://sidd-reddy.blogspot.com/2012/07/objects-functions-and-prototypes-in.html), first the author says "Every entity in Javascript is an object", and later it says "any new object can only be created as an instance of a function (even when you do 'var a = new Object;', Object is a function btw)".  The author is basically contradicting himself as far as I can see.

And I see the same chaotic comments in so many other resources on JavaScript. In Java it is easy, you know the first entity in any class Hierarchy is the Object class, but in JavaScript, all I see is chaos.

So, can someone please clarify if Object comes first or Function? What is the root.

Comment: The simple answer is the root of a prototype chain will always be `Object.prototype`, weird user manipulation aside.

Comment: Clearly the ultimate root of any prototype chain is `null`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the end of the line is `Object.prototype`, which is an object. This is what makes me think so:

```
Function.prototype;                    // the empty function object
Function.prototype.__proto__;          // the default Object prototype
Object.prototype;                      // the default Object prototype
Object.prototype.__proto__;            // null
```

The ECMAScript 5.1 specification states it like this:

1. In [15.3.4 Properties of the Function Prototype Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4):

   > The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Function prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object
2. And in [15.2.4 Properties of the Object Prototype Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4)

   > The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Object prototype object is `null`

Comment: I think you are correct. Seems like credible evidence that Object.prototype is the ultimate root of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for `Object.prototype` have to say:

> all objects inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype, although they may be overridden (except an Object with a null prototype, i.e. Object.create(null)).

In other words, `Object.prototype` is the root of **almost all** objects.  Both `Object` and `Function` are children of `Function.prototype`, which is itself a child of `Object.prototype`.

I find inheritance in Javascript to be far easier to understand when I ignore the constructor functions, and instead focus on prototype chains.  Doing this, for me, makes both the questions as well as the answers simpler; questions like:

- what is the prototype chain of an object?
- given two objects x and y, is x in y's prototype chain?  (or: does y inherit from x?)

You can easily investigate prototype chains yourself with this little snippet (helpful docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)):

```
function getPrototypes(obj) {
    var protos = [],
        parent = obj;
    while ( true ) {
        parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(parent);
        if ( parent === null ) {
            break;
        }
        protos.push(parent);
    }
    return protos;
}
```

According to this function, [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Glossary) don't have prototypes:

```
> getPrototypes(3)
TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object
```

So let's leave primitives out of the picture.
For objects, the hierarchy looks like this (where the children are indented to the right of their parent).  As far as I know, true multiple inheritance is impossible in Javascript, and so every object has a single parent, with the exception of `Object.prototype`, which has no parent:

- `Object.create(null)`
- Object.prototype

  - `arguments`
  - `Object.create(Object.prototype)`
  - `{}`

    - `Object.create({})`  -- *assuming `{}` is the object from the previous line, not a separate new object*
  - JSON
  - Math
  - Array.prototype

    - `[]`
    - `new Array()`
  - Function.prototype

    - Array
    - Object
    - Function
    - Number
    - Boolean
    - String
    - RegExp
    - `function MyFunction() {}`
    - `Object.keys`
    - `Object.prototype.toString`
    - `Object.prototype.toString.call`
    - `getPrototypes`
  - MyFunction.prototype

    - `new MyFunction()`
  - String.prototype

    - `new String('abc')`

      - `Object.create(new String('abc'))`
  - Number.prototype

    - `new Number(41)`
  - Boolean.prototype

    - `new Boolean()`
    - `new Object(false)`
  - RegExp.prototype

    - `/a/`

This is very confusing!  Notice that for most cases, `X.prototype` is not a prototype of `X`!  If we had some better terminology, the situation would probably be improved; however ... we don't :(  As you can see, constructors such as `Number` and `Boolean` are in a separate sub-hieararchy from the objects they produce.  Also, `Object` itself inherits from `Function.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`.

If you try these examples out, you will also find that using the `constructor` property is a poor way to inspect an object's prototypes, for a couple of reasons.  Given `var str1 = new String('abc'); var str2 = Object.create(str1);`, here's why:

1. an object can be an instance of multiple constructors: `str1 instanceof String` and `str1 instanceof Object` are both true.  This isn't reflected in the `constructor` property: `str1.contructor === String`
2. sometimes, we can't find a constructor function for each object in an object's prototype chain:  `Object.getPrototypeOf(str2).constructor === String`.  This is because the `constructor` property is inherited from `String.prototype`: both `str1.hasOwnProperty('constructor')` and `str2.hasOwnProperty('constructor')` are false, while `Object.getPrototypeOf(str1).hasOwnProperty('constructor')` is true.  Fortunately, you can use the [`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) method for this instead:  `str1.isPrototypeOf(str2)` is true.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding it.

Everything in Javascript (including all functions) is an object.

However, every object is an *instance* of a function.  (as specified by the object's `constructor` property)

Comment: Technically not everything is an object.  Primitives are not objects.

Comment: So the basic Object is an instance of a function being an instance of an Object?

Comment: ^ So everything is an Object. We found the end of the rainbow! *where is my pot of gold?*

Comment: @rlemon I believe it's at `Object.prototype.[[Prototype]]`; unfortunately, it's empty.

Comment: @SLaks, how can everything be an object, and then everything being an instance of function? that means an object is a function, but you just said everything is an object which means function is an object.  You are contradicting yourself just like the author of the resource I included.

Comment: `Function` is an object and a function. `Object` is an object and a function. All functions are instances of Function, and all objects (including functions) are instances of Object (tricky manipulation aside). Does that make any more sense?

Comment: GGG:  The thing is class hierarchy, no matter what language you use, has to have a root object from which everything starts.  Now, saying Function is an Object, and Object is a Function would not make sense. I think bfavaretto is correct in saying that Object.prototype.[[Prototype]] is the ultimate root of all objects in JavaScript.

Comment: @user1888243: Objects are not functions.  Objects are _instances of_ functions.

Comment: @user1888243 That's not correct. You'll never find an ultimate root element in C++.