# Which function is the root function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying understand core javascript. it's little bit confusing. When I evaluate

```
Object instanceof Function
```

its true , and `Function instanceof Object` its also true.

How and why?

Comment: `Object` and `Function` both refer to functions. Your question is confusing; you should re-read it.

Comment: You said you evaluated `Object instanceof Function` twice in your question.

Comment: Hint: evaluate `Object` and see what it returns.

Comment: You can have a look into this link  .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162038/in-javascript-what-is-the-ultimate-root-object-or-function

Comment: `Object` is the constructor function to create an object, so that is an instance of the `Function` type.

Comment: It's probably good to know at this point how `obj instanceof Func` works. It simply checks whether `Func.prototype` is in `obj`'s prototype chain. Since `Object` is a function, `Function.prototype` is in its prototype chain. Since `Function` is an object (every function is an object), `Object.prototype` is in its prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

Becouse `instanceof` is evaluating `Object` and checking if this has as an instance of `Function.constructor` in its prototype chain, and reverse:

```
Function.__proto__.__proto__ // Object.prototype
Object.__proto__ // Function.prototype
```

Anyway, you have the full explanation on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623598/1353771)

Comment: This doesn't explain why `Object` is an instance of `Function`.

Comment: And of course, Object is a function