# How to call a function and pass a variable with period notation

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I have seen this used before but am not sure how to actually implement it. How can a pass a function a variable with this syntax `foo.function()` , have foo passed as the input.
Ideally i would like to have it work like this

```
var foo = 'some string';

var myFunction = function(input){
    console.log(input);
}
foo.myFunction();

//should log 'some string'
```

I got the idea that this is possible from javascript frameworks like jquery where I can have `somevar.myFunction()`

Also I know that I can extend a pre-defined object but I would like to be able to run this function with any var provided.

Comment: what's wrong with `foo.function(foo)`?  At this point, the function that's associated with the object probably already knows about the object itself, so passing the instance of self is a bit of a weird pattern.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: If you include your actual code, it would be easier to tell what's going on.  This weird situation might be a symptom of large design problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162038/in-javascript-what-is-the-ultimate-root-object-or-function). Any object is chained to the Object's [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), ultimately. Which means, in a few words, that whenever an object does not own a property, it will check for it's prototype. The prototype in turn is an object, and so on and so forth.

Example:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function () {
    return "bar";
}

console.log("a string is an object".foo());
```

But, don't start using this until you really know what you're doing, because it's [not necessarily good practice](https://jslinterrors.com/extending-prototype-of-native-object) to extend a native object's prototype.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, hard to google when you don't know which words to look for. Thank you will check out link.

Comment: You don't have to go all the way to the top of the prototype chain, i.e. Objects's, you can do for String.prototype.foo.  The last advice @Gerard gave still holds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But given an example custom type in JavaScript:

```
function SomeType() {
    this.someVar = null;
    this.newFunction = function() {
        //do something, for example:
        this.someVar = "Hello World!";
    };
}

var foo = new SomeType();
foo.newFunction();
alert(foo.someVar);
```

Inside `newFunction()`, using the `this` identifier refers to the instance `foo`. So if inside `newFunction` you write:

```
this.someVar = "Hello World!";
```

Then `foo.someVar` will equal "Hello World!". So `foo` is not passed as an input but is inherently accessible using `this`.